# Pesquisa não funciona em Tela Modal do Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, dialog

Temos uma tela de pesquisa que funciona assim: Há uma tela principal. Nela um botão chama a tela de pesquisa. Essa tela é carregada em um `IFrame` que está dentro de um Modal `jquery-ui(Dialog)`. Nessa tela(pesquisa) seleciono alguns filtros e ao clicar no botão pesquisa, me abre um grid com o resultado da pesquisa. Bem, quando eu seleciono um CPF ou No. de Prontuário, por exemplo, ele fecha a tela e na página chamadora original, os `Textbox` são então preenchidos com esses valores. O que está acontecendo. Essa tela de pesquisa, antes foi desenvolvida dentro de `ShowModalDialog`. Por essa razão, ele funciona apenas no `IE(Modo Modal)`. No `Chrome` ele sobe normalmente, mas não de forma Modal, razão que a empresa quer que seja validado no Chrome também, mas mantendo a funcionalidade que há hoje no IE. Então, partimos para uma solução `jquery`, por enquanto para atender essa especificação, mas o problema é esse. Mesmo clicando não dá nenhum erro, mas não acontece nada. A pesquisa não completa. Alguém me disse pára mudar para o `ajax` e ver como funciona, mas gostaria de saber se com o `Dialog` do `jquery` dá pra fazer.

Veja a tela abaixo. Ao clicar em contrato, o Modal deveria ser fechado e na tela de fundo, o campo Contrato deveria ser preenchido e o campo ao lado(ready only) deveria ser preenchido com o Nome.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao clicar no contrato ou nome, qualquer um que tenha um "link", é chamada uma função javascript() e é ela quem fecham o Dialog e popula a tela de baixo(página chamadora). Veja a função abaixo:

```
function selecionar(num_contrato, cod_ts_contrato, nome_entidade){
    <%if trim(strAction) = "" then %>
        //ABRIU POPUP
        var txt_chamada = '';
        try {
            var oMyObject = window.dialogArguments;
            txt_chamada = "oMyObject";
            var aux = oMyObject.document;
        } catch (e) {
            txt_chamada = "window.parent.opener";
        }

      try{
           //COD_TS_CONTRATO
         <%if trim(txt_nome_campo_cod_ts)<>"" then %>
            var ocod_ts_contrato = eval(txt_chamada + ".document.form01.<%Response.write txt_nome_campo_cod_ts%>");
         <%else%>
            var ocod_ts_contrato = eval(txt_chamada + ".document.form01.cod_ts_contrato");
         <%end if %>

           if (ocod_ts_contrato != null )
               ocod_ts_contrato.value = cod_ts_contrato;

           //NUM_CONTRATO
           <%if trim(txt_nome_campo_cod)<>"" then%>
               var onum_contrato = eval(txt_chamada + ".document.form01.<%Response.write txt_nome_campo_cod%>");
           <%else%>
               var onum_contrato = eval(txt_chamada + ".document.form01.num_contrato");
           <%end if %>

           if (onum_contrato != null )
               onum_contrato.value = num_contrato;

           //NOME_CONTRATO
           <%if trim(txt_nome_campo_desc)<>"" then%>
               var onome_entidade = eval(txt_chamada + ".document.form01.<%Response.write txt_nome_campo_desc%>");
           <%else%>
               var onome_entidade = eval(txt_chamada + ".document.form01.nome_contrato");
           <%end if%>

           if (onome_entidade != null )
               onome_entidade.value = nome_entidade;

           <%if trim(funcao_executar) <> "" then%>
               try{
                   var aux = eval(txt_chamada+".<%Response.write funcao_executar%>");
               }catch(e){
                   window.returnValue = 'window.<%Response.write funcao_executar%>';            
               }
           <%end if%>

         <%if ucase(indsubmit) = "TRUE" then%>
            eval(txt_chamada + ".document.form01.submit()");
         <%else %>
            //Somente joga o Focus se o campo existir, e estiver desabilitado
            if (onum_contrato != null && onum_contrato.disabled==false && onum_contrato.enabled==true)
               onum_contrato.focus();
         <%end if%>
      }catch(e){

           //COD_TS_CONTRATO
         <%if trim(txt_nome_campo_cod_ts)<>"" then %>
            var ocod_ts_contrato = eval(txt_chamada + ".<%Response.write txt_nome_campo_cod_ts%>");
         <%else%>
            var ocod_ts_contrato = eval(txt_chamada + ".cod_ts_contrato");
         <%end if %>

           if (ocod_ts_contrato != null )
               ocod_ts_contrato.value = cod_ts_contrato;

           //NUM_CONTRATO
           <%if trim(txt_nome_campo_cod)<>"" then%>
               var onum_contrato = eval(txt_chamada + ".<%Response.write txt_nome_campo_cod%>");
           <%else%>
               var onum_contrato = eval(txt_chamada + ".num_contrato");
           <%end if %>

           if (onum_contrato != null )
               onum_contrato.value = num_contrato;

           //NOME_CONTRATO
           <%if trim(txt_nome_campo_desc)<>"" then%>
               var onome_entidade = eval(txt_chamada + ".<%Response.write txt_nome_campo_desc%>");
           <%else%>
               var onome_entidade = eval(txt_chamada + ".nome_contrato");
           <%end if%>

           if (onome_entidade != null )
               onome_entidade.value = nome_entidade;

           <%if trim(funcao_executar) <> "" then%>
               /*try{
                   var aux = eval(txt_chamada+".<%Response.write funcao_executar%>");
               }catch(e){
                   window.returnValue = 'window.<%Response.write funcao_executar%>';            
               }*/
               var opener_document = oMyObject.ownerDocument;
               var opener_window = opener_document.defaultView || opener_document.parentWindow;

                  try {
                     eval("opener_window." + "<%Response.write funcao_executar%>");
                  } catch (e) {
                     window.returnValue = "window." + "<%Response.write funcao_executar%>";
                  }

           <%end if%>

         <%if ucase(indsubmit) = "TRUE" then%>
            eval(txt_chamada + ".submit()");
         <%else %>
            //Somente joga o Focus se o campo existir, e estiver desabilitado
            if (onum_contrato != null && onum_contrato.disabled==false && onum_contrato.enabled==true)
               onum_contrato.focus();
         <%end if%>
      }  
      parent.self.close();

    <%else %>
        //ABRIU NORMAL ENTAO DAR SUBMIT
        document.form01.cod_ts_contrato.value   = cod_ts_contrato;
        document.form01.num_contrato.value      = num_contrato;
        document.form01.action = '<%Response.write strAction & "?PT=" & Request("PT")%>';
        document.form01.submit();
    <%end if %>
}
```

Comecei a fazer as alterações e veja o seguinte. No pedaço de código abaixo, no primeiro alert() eu tenho o valor da variável, já no segundo não é chamado. Acredito que ele se perca nessa situação:

```
.document.form01.<%Response.write txt_nome_campo_cod_ts%>");
```

Acho que eu deveria trocar para `document.getElementsByName()`. Estou tentando fazer a alteração sugerida pelo TobyMosque, mas confesso estou tendo alguma dificuldade parra entender, mas acho ser o caminho.

```
try{
           alert(cod_ts_contrato); 

           //COD_TS_CONTRATO
         <%if trim(txt_nome_campo_cod_ts)<>"" then %>
            var ocod_ts_contrato = eval(txt_chamada + ".document.form01.<%Response.write txt_nome_campo_cod_ts%>");
         <%else%>
            var ocod_ts_contrato = eval(txt_chamada + ".document.form01.cod_ts_contrato");
         <%end if %>

           if (ocod_ts_contrato != null )
               ocod_ts_contrato.value = cod_ts_contrato;

           alert(cod_ts_contrato);
```

Assim ficou a função com a ajuda do TobyMosque.

```
function selecionar(num_contrato, cod_ts_contrato, nome_entidade){
    <%if trim(strAction) = "" then %>
        //ABRIU POPUP
        var txt_chamada = '';
        if (window.dialogArguments) {
            txt_chamada = "window.dialogArguments";
        } else if (window.parent.opener) {
            txt_chamada = "window.parent.opener";
        } else if (window.parent.frameElement) {
            if (window.parent.frameElement.ownerDocument.defaultView) {
                txt_chamada = "window.parent.frameElement.ownerDocument.defaultView";
            } else {
                txt_chamada = "window.parent.frameElement.ownerDocument.parentWindow";
            }
        }

      try{

           //COD_TS_CONTRATO

            var janela = null;
            if (window.dialogArguments) {
                janela = window.dialogArguments;
            } else if (window.parent.opener) {
                janela = window.parent.opener;
            } else if (window.parent.frameElement) {
                var documento = window.parent.frameElement.ownerDocument
                var janela = documento.defaultView || documento.parentWindow;
            }

            if (janela) {
                var txt_nome_campo_cod_ts = "<%= trim(txt_nome_campo_cod_ts) %>" || "cod_ts_contrato";
                var txt_nome_campo_cod = "<%= trim(txt_nome_campo_cod) %>" || "num_contrato";

                var ocod_ts_contrato = janela.document.form01[txt_nome_campo_cod_ts];
                var onum_contrato = janela.document.form01[txt_nome_campo_cod];
//                var onum_contrato = janela.document.getElementsByName(txt_nome_campo_cod);
            }

//         //NUM_CONTRATO
      }catch(e){

// Aqui código do Catch. Retirei para não ficar grande a edição.

      }  
      parent.self.close();
      $("#dialog1", janela).dialog("close");

    <%else %>
        //ABRIU NORMAL ENTAO DAR SUBMIT
        document.form01.cod_ts_contrato.value   = cod_ts_contrato;
        document.form01.num_contrato.value      = num_contrato;
        document.form01.action = '<%Response.write strAction & "?PT=" & Request("PT")%>';
        document.form01.submit();
    <%end if %>
}
```

Comment: Caso alguém tenha alguma idéia para funcionar, mesmo que não seja pelo jquery-ui(Dialog Modal), é bem vinda, desde que o comportamento da tela de pesquisa seja de forma Modal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pnet, pelo o que me lembro das suas perguntas antigas, esta pagina que você está carregando no iFrame antes era aberta em um pop-up.

Desta forma, esta pagina deveria está se comunicando com a pagina que à abriu da seguinte forma:

```
if (window.opener) {
    //manipula os DOM da outra tela (a que abriu a atual) atraves do window.opener
}
```

porem agora você está exibindo esta tela através de um iFrame, então a forma de acessar a tela que a solicitou é um pouco diferente.

```
if (window.frameElement) {
    //manipula os DOM da tela pai (a que solicitou o iFrame) atraves do window.frameElement
}
```

o código abaixo tenta normalizar isto, procurando a janela parente, independente desta ser uma tela separada ou o documento a que o iFrame pertence.

```
var janela = null;
if (window.frameElement) {
    var documento = window.frameElement.ownerDocument
    var janela = documento.defaultView || documento.parentWindow;
} else if (window.opener) {
    var janela = window.opener;
}

if (janela) {
    //manipula os DOM da tela principal através da variável janela.
}
```

**EDIT**

tente substituir o seguinte bloco:

```
var txt_chamada = '';
try {
    var oMyObject = window.dialogArguments;
    txt_chamada = "oMyObject";
    var aux = oMyObject.document;
} catch (e) {
    txt_chamada = "window.parent.opener";
}
```

por este:

```
var txt_chamada = '';
if (window.dialogArguments) {
    txt_chamada = "window.dialogArguments";
} else if (window.parent.opener) {
    txt_chamada = "window.parent.opener";
} else if (window.parent.frameElement) {
    if (window.parent.frameElement.ownerDocument.defaultView) {
        txt_chamada = "window.parent.frameElement.ownerDocument.defaultView";
    } else {
        txt_chamada = "window.parent.frameElement.ownerDocument.parentWindow";
    }
}
```

**SUGESTÃO**

Tente evitar usar `eval()` de forma demasiada, especialmente quando não é necessário, o seu codigo poderia ser algo como o abaixo:

```
var txt_chamada = '';
try {
    var oMyObject = window.dialogArguments;
    txt_chamada = "oMyObject";
    var aux = oMyObject.document;
} catch (e) {
    txt_chamada = "window.parent.opener";
}

try {
    <%if trim(txt_nome_campo_cod_ts)<>"" then %>
        var ocod_ts_contrato = eval(txt_chamada + ".document.form01.<%Response.write txt_nome_campo_cod_ts%>");
    <%else%>
        var ocod_ts_contrato = eval(txt_chamada + ".document.form01.cod_ts_contrato");
    <%end if %>

    <%if trim(txt_nome_campo_cod)<>"" then%>
       var onum_contrato = eval(txt_chamada + ".document.form01.<%Response.write txt_nome_campo_cod%>");
    <%else%>
       var onum_contrato = eval(txt_chamada + ".document.form01.num_contrato");
    <%end if %>
} catch (e) {

}
```

por algo mais limpo:

```
function selecionar(num_contrato, cod_ts_contrato, nome_entidade){
<%if trim(strAction) = "" then %>
    //ABRIU POPUP
    var janela = null;
    var isIFrame = false;
    var isPopUp = false;        
    if (window.dialogArguments) {
        isPopUp = true;
        janela = window.dialogArguments;
    } else if (window.parent.opener) {
        isPopUp = true;
        janela = window.parent.opener;
    } else if (window.parent.frameElement) {
        isIFrame = true;
        var documento = window.parent.frameElement.ownerDocument
        var janela = documento.defaultView || documento.parentWindow;
    }

    if (janela) {
        var form01 = janela.document.form01 || janela;
        var cod_ts_contrato_id = "<%= trim(txt_nome_campo_cod_ts) %>" || "cod_ts_contrato";
        var num_contrato_id = "<%= trim(txt_nome_campo_cod) %>" || "num_contrato";
        var nome_contrato_id = "<%= trim(txt_nome_campo_desc) %>" || "nome_contrato";
        var funcao_executar_id = "<%= trim(funcao_executar) %>";
        var indsubmit = "<%= lcase(indsubmit) %>" === "true";

        var ocod_ts_contrato = form01[cod_ts_contrato_id];
        var onum_contrato = form01[num_contrato_id];
        var onome_entidade = form01[nome_contrato_id];
        var ofuncao_executar = funcao_executar_id ? janela[funcao_executar_id] : null;

        if (ocod_ts_contrato) ocod_ts_contrato.value = cod_ts_contrato;
        if (onum_contrato) onum_contrato.value = cod_ts_contrato;
        if (onome_entidade ) onome_entidade .value = nome_entidade;
        if (typeof ofuncao_executar === 'function') ofuncao_executar();

        if (indsubmit) {
            form01.submit();
        } else if (onum_contrato != null && onum_contrato.disabled==false && onum_contrato.enabled==true) {
            onum_contrato.focus();
        }
    }

    if (isIFrame) {
        janela.fecharModal();
    } 

    if (isPopUp) {
        parent.self.close();
    }

<%else %>
    //ABRIU NORMAL ENTAO DAR SUBMIT
    document.form01.cod_ts_contrato.value = cod_ts_contrato;
    document.form01.num_contrato.value = num_contrato;
    document.form01.action = '<%Response.write strAction & "?PT=" & Request("PT")%>';
    document.form01.submit();
<%end if %>
}
```

**JS PAGINA PAI**

```
var fecharModal = function () {
    var dialog = $(janela.document.getElementById("dialog"));
    dialog.dialog("close");
}
```